# Vue, after push to array, all properties react simultaneously

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue and I am having an issue with its reactivity

I have a Vue component where I declare some data and some methods (trigger by a button):

```
data: function() {
 return {
  options: [],
  option_template: {
   id: '',
   name: ''
  }
 }
},
methods: {
 add() {
  this.props.push(this.option_template)
 }
}
```

Then I have a loop on my component to go trough its options:

```
<div v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
 <label>{{ option.name }}</label>
 <input type="text" v-model="option.name">
</div>
<button type="button" @click.prevent="add">Add new</button>
```

All works well but when I add a new option by clicking on the button then every input affect all options and the changes are replicated in all `options.name`.

I found out that I can avoid declaring `option_template` in the data and then just push it like this:

```
this.props.push({
       id: '',
       name: ''
      })
```

This sort my issue but I actually has a much longer and complicated `option_template`.
How can I make `Vue` to recognise the `push(this.option_template)` as some kind of "new instance" of `option_template`?

Comment: you can't ... because `this.option_template` is exactly one object, i.e. it IS `this.option_template` - so, changing its property values is going to effect anything that references that single object

Comment: by the way, it's not the push to array that is causing your problem, it's changing property values in `this.option_template` that does it

Comment: To elaborate on the linked duplicate, you want `this.options.push({ ...this.optionsTemplate })`

Comment: @Phil thats super useful, sorry I did not know how to express myself properly so I could not find the other question